# How to removeClass with exception in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass, getelementsbyclassname

i have a little jQuery case. So, i want to remove all of block classes but with little exception - if this div/block have some classes every of them will be deleated but one specify not. I'v try something like this but it's not work.

```
$('#rounded_items').removeClass(function(){
    $('#rounded_items').not.getElementsByClassName('small_menu');
}).addClass('main_menu');
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you put it on jsfiddle if it is not solved yet?

Comment: all construction is more complicated and work's with ajax... :(

Comment: Well just make a sample static example and put it on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's should be unique, so all you have to do is check that the **single** element you are targeting does not have the class before you remove the classes :

```
var isSmall = $('#rounded_items').is('.small_menu');
$('#rounded_items').attr('class', isSmall ? 'main_menu' : '');
```

Comment: ok, but this is exeption with this class, i need to remove classes even if this block has this class and love this one

Comment: Not sure I get it, but try checking if it has the class first, then remove all classes and add the class back etc.

Comment: ok, it's work but i have some time interval (maybe 0,5s) when this element does't have any class and lose css :(

Comment: Edited my answer again, try that approach as it will just replace the entire class attribute with the new class or nothing at all !

Comment: ok, i'v add some animation effect and it's work corectly - much thx for interest

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what exactly you're trying to do, but my best guess would be something like this:

```
$('#rounded_items:not(.small_menu)').removeClass().addClass('main_menu');
```

... which will replace all class names with just `main_menu` to all items with ID `rounded_items` (!!!) except those with class `small_menu`.

Do take note that IDs **should be unique**. Can't stress that enough. So it doesn't make sense to select by ID *and expect multiple elements* so that you can filter by class further.

Comment: s/should/MUST/ - non-unique IDs will cause nothing but problems

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski ~ you can just chain it prior to the `.addClass` call. I'll put in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
$('#rounded_items').removeClass(function(){
     var el = $('.small_menu');
    $('#rounded_items').not(el);
}).addClass('main_menu');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just check if the object has this class which should not be removed. If it has it - remove all classes and add the needed class. Something like this:

```
if ($("#item").hasClass("neededClass")){
   $("#item").removeClass();
   $("#item").addClass("neededClass");
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: i need to have two separated classes for this element